# React Redux state is not getting updated with alone dependency

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this piece of code, I expect to debugger to hit point at useEffect array dependencies, why i have to include unnecessary dependency as well to work this code,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        preSelected: state.getTabReducer.preSelected
    }
}    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Table);

const { preSelected } = props;

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(preSelected);
}, [preSelected])
```

this will not work on first attempt, but strangely works on some other attempts, but still not always,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        preSelected: state.getTabReducer.preSelected,
        available: state.getTabReducer.available // WORKS BUT I DONT WANT TO ADD THIS
    }
}    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Table);


const {preSelected} = props; //WORKS WHY???
//const preSelected = props.preSelected; //WORKS WHY???
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(preSelected);
}, [preSelected])
```

But, like this way it works? Why second way works? but fails first way??
Then, i figure out that its nothing to do with `Object.assign`, its about putting `available: state.getTabReducer.available` , it works why this is such behavior, why i have to add it even when i didnt used it?

I am also getting,

```
Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.
```

Comment: Please define "not work on first attempt".

Comment: @palindrom means first piece of code doesnt work, second piece is fix but not clean approach

Comment: What do you expect to see that doesnt happen? Is it the log?

Comment: Yeah, useEffect doesn't get called, so log not getting called

Comment: Do you really want to do `const { preSelected } = props.preSelected;`or what you trying to do is `const { preSelected } = props;` or `const preSelected = props.preSelected`?

Comment: oh yeah, you are right, fixed it question

Comment: Do you also need to fix this part because this creates a new object having properties of `props.preselected`, not having `preSelected` as a property: `const preSelected = Object.assign({}, props.preSelected);`